# Scala Interpreter Blocks

Tags: scala, interpreter

Currently I am struggling with interpreting Blocks in Scala. My code looks something like this:

AST:

```
case class Braces(value: Node) extends Node
case class Block(value: List[Node]) extends Node
case class VariableDeclaration(name: String, value: Node) extends Node
case class VariableAssignment(name: String, value: Node) extends Node
case class CallFunction(name: String, value: List[Node]) extends Node
case class Variable(name: String) extends Node
case class Integer(int: Int) extends Node
```

Interpreter:
(I do not want to change the signature nor the parameter of the interpret function. My preferred solution includes a global stack of Environments)

```
    sealed trait iValue
    type VarEnv = Map[String, iValue]

    def interpret(env: VarEnv, body: Node): iValue = body match
    {
        case Block(value: List[Node]) => {
          ???
        }
        case VariableDeclaration(....)
        case VariableAssignment(....)
        case CallFunction(....)
    }
```

A sample test case should look like this:

```
  {
    $a = 5;
    $b = 4;
    {
      $a = 2;
      b = add(a, b);
    };
    add(b, { a; });
  }
  iValue(11))
```

How do I implement this including shadowing of variables?

Answer (score 2):

I've just completed your code to a tiny functioning interpreter, here is a brief walk-through.

1. You want to reassign variables, so it looks like a little imperative language. Thus, we will treat statements and expressions separately. Here are the AST elements relevant for the example:

   ```
   sealed trait Stmt
   case class DeclAsgn(varName: String, rhs: Expr) extends Stmt
   case class Asgn(varName: String, rhs: Expr) extends Stmt
   case class Print(expr: Expr) extends Stmt
   case class Block(stmts: List[Stmt]) extends Stmt

   sealed trait Expr
   case class Num(n: Int) extends Expr
   case class Sub(a: Expr, b: Expr) extends Expr
   case class Var(name: String) extends Expr
   ```
2. We will want to *evaluate* expressions. Thus, we have to define what *values* are. For now, there are only integer values (`iValue`?) and a default `None`-value (as in Python-`None`, not the Scala-`None`):

   ```
   sealed trait Value
   case object NoneValue extends Value
   case class IntValue(i: Int) extends Value
   ```
3. Now the interesting part: environments. Notice that differentiating between "environment" and "block environment" is insufficient: the blocks can be nested to an arbitrary depth, so you need a whole *stack* of variable bindings:

   ```
   case class Env(stack: List[Map[String, Value]]) extends (String => Value) {
     def apply(varName: String) = stack match {
       case Nil => throw new Error("Undefined var: " + varName)
       case h :: t => h.getOrElse(varName, Env(t)(varName))
     }
     def enterBlock: Env = Env(Map.empty[String, Value] :: stack)
     def exitBlock: Env = Env(stack.tail)
     def withDeclaredVar(name: String): Env = {
       val h :: t = stack
       if (h contains name) throw new Error(s"Variable $name already declared")
       else Env(h.updated(name, NoneValue) :: t)
     }
     def updated(name: String, value: Value): Env = stack match {
       case Nil => throw new Error("Could not set variable " + name)
       case h :: t => 
         if (h contains name) Env(h.updated(name, value) :: t)
         else Env(h :: Env(t).updated(name, value).stack)
     }
     def withDeclaredVar(name: String, value: Value): Env = {
       this.withDeclaredVar(name).updated(name, value)
     }
   }
   ```

   Now, every time you enter a block, you can simply put a fresh empty `Map[String, Value]` on the top of this stack, so that all new declared variables are inserted into this map (shadowing previous levels), and once you are done with the block, you can simply discard the topmost map (unshadowing the previously shadowed levels).

   Here is also a little helper method for instantiating the initial empty environment in which the whole program runs:

   ```
   object Env {
     def empty = Env(List(Map.empty[String, Value]))
   }
   ```
4. Once all the data structures are set up correctly, evaluation of expressions and interpretation of side-effecty statements is straightforward:

   ```
   def eval(env: Env, expr: Expr): Value = expr match {
     case Var(v) => env(v)
     case Sub(a, b) => (eval(env, a), eval(env, b)) match {
       case (IntValue(va), IntValue(vb)) => IntValue(va - vb)
       case sthElse => throw new Error("`Sub` not applicable to " + sthElse)
     }
     case Num(n) => IntValue(n)
   }

   def interpret(env: Env, stmt: Stmt): Env = stmt match {
     case Block(stmts) =>
       stmts.foldLeft(env.enterBlock)(interpret).exitBlock
     case Print(e) => {
       println(eval(env, e))
       env
     }
     case DeclAsgn(v, r) => {
       val rhsVal = eval(env, r)
       env.withDeclaredVar(v, rhsVal)
     }
     case Asgn(v, r) => {
       var rhsVal = eval(env, r)
       env.updated(v, rhsVal)
     }
   }
   ```
5. Just in order to see something, let's also quickly define a pretty-printing function:

   ```
   def prettyPrint(prog: Stmt): String = prog match {
     case DeclAsgn(v, r) => s"$$${v} = ${prettyPrint(r)}"
     case Asgn(v, r) => s"${v} = ${prettyPrint(r)}"
     case Print(e) => s"print(${prettyPrint(e)})"
     case Block(xs) => xs
       .map(prettyPrint)
       .mkString(";\n")
       .split("\n")
       .map("  " + _)
       .mkString("{\n", "\n", "\n}")
   }

   def prettyPrint(expr: Expr): String = expr match {
     case Num(n) => n.toString
     case Sub(a, b) => s"sub(${prettyPrint(a)},${prettyPrint(b)})"
     case Var(v) => v
   }
   ```

Now to your example. I've inserted a few `print`-statements so we can observe the intermediate results. Here is the AST as code:

```
    /* example */ {
      import scala.language.implicitConversions
      val c = Var("c")
      val d = Var("d")
      implicit def intToNum(i: Int): Expr = Num(i)
      val ast = Block(List(
        DeclAsgn("c", 5),
        DeclAsgn("d", 4),
        Block(List(
          Asgn("c", 3),
          DeclAsgn("d", 45),
          Print(c),
          Print(d),
          Print(Sub(d, c))
        )),
        Print(c),
        Print(d),
        Print(Sub(c, d))
      ))
      println(prettyPrint(ast))
      interpret(Env.empty, ast)
    }
```

Here is the pretty-printed version:

```
{
  $c = 5;
  $d = 4;
  {
    c = 3;
    $d = 45;
    print(c);
    print(d);
    print(sub(d,c))
  };
  print(c);
  print(d);
  print(sub(c,d))
}
```

And here is the output:

```
IntValue(3)
IntValue(45)
IntValue(42)
IntValue(3)
IntValue(4)
IntValue(-1)
```

As you can see, the value of `c` is shadowed and then unshadowed, the value of `d` set in the inner block is simply discarded.